# iPhone auto-zoom while interacting with selection list

Tags: iphone, mobile, web

We are working on a mobile website framework and recently found the below issue on iphone.

Issue : when I visit the form elements using the iPhone and select the dropdown lists, the display zooms in a little to make the list visible. When I select an option and tap Done, the display remains zoomed; I have to pinch to get back to how it was.

Is there a way to make the screen scale back to the proper size?

Thanks / Lokesh